# Why not free electrons in atom doesn't radiates em waves\photons?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons, atomic-physics

Why not free electrons in atom doesn't radiates em waves\photons, although they move with acceleration? Like 1s electron of Titan, it doesn't emits em waves, yes? Why?

Comment: There are no free electrons in an atom.

Comment: Such electrons are not free.  Google Bohr's quantum hypothesis.

Comment: @LewisMiller, but they move, and move with acceleration, yes?

Comment: What's "Titan"? Titanium? Electrons bound to atoms are by definition not free electrons. If a lower energy state is available, those electrons would indeed tend to transition to the lower energy state and emit a photon via spontaneous emission: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission But when there isn't a lower energy state available, the electron can't emit a EM wave.

Comment: @enumaris, but even if there is no free lower energy state electron all the same moves?

Comment: The electron occupies a stationary state solution to Schoedinger's equation. No, it is not, in fact, accelerating.

Comment: @JonCuster, but moves?

Comment: It is a stationary state. The expectation value does not change. Welcome to quantum mechanics...

Comment: @JonCuster, confused. Moves, not, or undefined?

Comment: The electron is a wave function, it is not a point particle orbiting around like the moon around the Earth. This is a fundamental outcome of quantum mechanics. It does not 'move' or 'accelerate' in the way you seem to think - it is not a classical entity.

Comment: Well, ok.. It's offtop, but maybe you know, why *positively* accelerating particle radiates em waves, if it doesn't loses energy

Comment: @JonCuster could you write that as an answer please? I was going to write my own but then saw this comment, which is pretty complete (but could be expounded upon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the classical model of an atom as a little solar system simply doesn't work for atoms. That was the message of the quantum physicists starting with Bohr (1913) and Heisenberg et al (1925).

We don't know what an atom "looks like" inside. Hard little balls going in orbits? Um, we cannot watch them. Some quantum field sloshing about? Some strange state that we cannot observe in detail.

So the early quantum physicists, starting with Bohr, simply declared that electrons in atoms can only have various discrete states, and that no radiation is emitted while an electron *remains* in a state, only when it *transitions* between two states. Why is this? Well, we don't know. But it's what the experimental data tells us. Quantum physics tells us how to calculate things, like energies and chemical bonds, but it doesn't tell us *why* it is so.

Answer (score 1):

The free electrons you refer to, are free electrons in a vacuum, not bount to atoms.

Now electrons in an atom are bound to the nucleus. These electrons exist as per QM at a certain energy level around the nucleus. Their wavefunction describes the probability distribution of their position for all of space. They do not classically orbit the nucleus, but as per QM they exist around it, and the wavefunction describes the probability of finding the electron at a certain position around the nucleus.

Now you are referring to accelerating charges, electrons, emitting photons. That is how radio antennas work, and in that case, the antenna (metal lattice) has electrons that are loosely bound to the atoms. These electrons are not free. They are loosely bound, so they can (because of an external EM field) move to the next atom. This is called drift velocity, and is pretty slow, but because the electrons are densely packed, the electricity moves in the metal with close to light speed. Now these electrons in the metal antenna are accelerating, and emitting photons.

In your case, the electrons around the nucleus are not accelerating. They exist around the nucleus as per QM at a certain stable energy level. These electrons do not accelerate. They have a certain kinetic energy, that keeps them away from the nucleus, and they have a certain EM charge, that pulls them to the nucleus, and the two forces equalize, and keep the electron at a stable energy level.

These bound electrons around the nucleus can emit photons, for a few reasons. There is spontaneous emission, when the electron emits a photon and moves to a certain lower energy level when a lower energy level is available.

Answer (score -1):

In quantum mechanics there are no individual electrons which dart about like ping bong balls. But there is an electric charge density which can be derived from the total wave function of the system. In general this charge density is not stationary. To the extent that it is moving, oscillating or accelerating, it will emit or absorb radiation. And that emission or absorption can be calculated exactly by using Maxwell's Equations.

The absoption of light, which occurs as a result of the coupling of the conduction band electrons in a metal to the free electron  states outside the metal is, governed by Maxwell's Equations (together with Schroedinger's Equation). The linewidths of the absorption lines in the hydrogen spectrum are governed by Maxwell's Equations (together with Schroedinger's equation). The emission of light from a heated tungsten filament is governed by Maxwell's Equations, as applied to the oscillating charge distributions within that metal filament (which are given by Schroedinger's Equation.)

It is not necessary to talk about photons to explain any of these things, and it is not particularly helpful either.

Comment: "In quantum mechanics there are no individual electrons which dart about like ping bong balls." This is overstated. Elementary point particles do play a role in QED. There are individual electrons.

Comment: Do they dart about like ping pong balls?

Comment: More like ping pong balls that teleport for short distances over and over at close to the speed of light. QED differs from the classical Maxwell's Equations in important respects in this way. Under Maxwell's Equations alone, for example, transistors wouldn't work.